# Easy way to plot X and Y in an array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, graphics, plot, doublebuffered

Hello I am making a double buffer in C# and I need to find out a formula to plot the X and Y coordinates in my array. Currently I am using a loop to plot my X and Y but it takes along time to do it. (NOTE I CANNOT USE A MULTI DIMENSIONAL ARRAY!!!)

Comment: Can you show us what you have?  Also define a long time?  Is 1 second too long?  What time are you looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int[] buffer = new int[width * height];

void Plot(int x, int y, int color)
{
    buffer[y* width + x] = color;
}
```

**EDIT**

To plot longer blocks you could use the [Array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx).Copy functions

If that is still too slow you could [fallback to unsafe code to fill the array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288474%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

May be [MathGL](http://mathgl.sf.net/) (GPL plotting library) may satisfy yours needs. It have no direct C# interface (in fact, it can be built by SWIG but I never try it). But, as I know, the C-functions can be called from C# easily.